# Look up values a List<T> and use as conditions in a where statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need to be able to select data based on if a value in one of the properties exist in a list of other values. Right now I have this:

```
//Just the definition of the different list objects for clarity
List<RouteDataItem> routeData;
List<RouteCodeItem> routeCodes;

var qrData = from d in routeData
             where d.Route == RouteType && q.RouteCode == [HERE IS WHERE I'M STUCK]
             select q;
```

The routeData is a List of an object and so is the RouteCode, so basically I would like to make it something like this (pseudo LINQ / SQL type code although this is pure LINQ2Objects):

```
//Just the definition of the different list objects for clarity
List<RouteDataItem> routeData;
List<RouteCodeItem> routeCodes;

var qrData = from d in routeData
             where d.Route == RouteType && q.RouteCode in (routeCodes.ValidCode)                 
              select q;
```

I hope you guys understand my hieroglyphs. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it Linq-To-Sql or -To-Objects?

Comment: also you want to take RouteData or RouteCode? (as you wrote select q and not select d in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
 where d.Route == RouteType && routeCodes.Any(x => x.ValidCode == d.RouteCode)
```

Or with Method Syntax:-

```
var qrData = routeData.Where(d => d.Route == RouteType && 
                                  routeCodes.Any(r => r.ValidCode == d.RouteCode));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Contains` or `Any`:

```
var qrData = from d in routeData
             where d.Route == RouteType 
             && routeCodes.Select(x => x.ValidCode).Contains(d.RouteCode)                
             select q;
```

or

```
var qrData = from d in routeData
             where d.Route == RouteType 
             && routeCodes.Any(x => x.ValidCode == d.RouteCode)
             select q;
```

for faster lookup performance you could create a `HashSet<T>`:

```
var validCodes = new HashSet<whateveritis>(routeCodes.Select(x => x.ValidCode));
var qrData = from d in routeData
             where d.Route == RouteType && validCodes.Contains(d.RouteCode)
             select q;
```

Comment: watch out select q (not sure if it was on purpose for routeCodes or a mistake and it should be d for routedata)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
var qrData = from d in routeData
             where d.Route == RouteType && routeCodes.Any(x => x.ValidCode == d.RouteCode)
             select d;
```

Although not 100% sure what the resulting select should be.